# CSS to make text appear below picture

Tags: html, css, web

98.214.131.200/index.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Peoria Triathlon Club</title>
    <meta  charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="http://tri-peoria.org">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="/join">Join</a></li>
    <li><a href="/members">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="/training">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/tripeoria/">Facebook</a></li>
    <ab><a href="/about">Peoria Triathlon Club</a></ab>
</ul>
<ul id=main>
<p>Main</p>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

98.214.131.200/style.css

```
body {
    background:#000 url(bg.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #c1c1c1;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}

#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#main{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

How do I make things in the main div appear below the background picture and still have the navigation bar at the top?
Current code can been seen at http:// 98.214.131.200

Comment: Do you mean below as in z-order, or below as in along the y-axis (vertically)?

Comment: Tyler, please provide the markup as well, not just the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your "main" container to a `div` instead of a `ul` (unless you have a compelling reason to make it a `ul`...you can always have a `ul` inside your main `div`).
2. Add a `margin-top` property to your `#main` css to bump it down from the nav bar an appropriate amount.

So in index.php:

```
<div id="main">
<p>Main</p>
</div>
```

And in style.css:

```
#main {
    margin-top: 240px; /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

You can dump the `display: inline-block` from your main css, and you may not need the `float:left` either depending on your subsequent intentions.

You may also need to drop the `background-size: cover` from your body's css, or the image may grow to cover you main div as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see exactly what you're trying to achieve, but you can add a "padding-top" to your body equal to the height of your background image.

body {  padding-top: 50px; } //assuming your bg.jpg is 50px height

And check if you really need that float on your #main.

Comment: If I add padding to the body it moves my navigation bar down as well. If you go to 98.214.131.200/index.php you'll see my current design. Right now I'm trying to move the "main" text below the "Swim, Bike, Run" picture.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
body {
background-color: #000000;
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #C1C1C1;
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

#main {
    margin-top: 370px;
}
```